# Using CSS to set font properties on multiple tables

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-tables, definition

In HTML, if we want to use CSS to set font properties of font in all tables, we use something like this:

```
<style>
table {
    width: 10%;
    border: 0;
    font-size:1;
}
</style>
```

My question is: What if I want different font settings for different tables? For example, I have 3 types of tables. Some of which, I want fonts to be size 8, some table to be size 6..etc.

This way **won't** work (This is just an illustration what I wanted to do):

```
<style>
table1 {
    width: 10%;
    border: 0;
    font-size:6;
}
table2 {
    width: 2%;
    border: 1;
    font-size:8;
}
table3 {
    border: 2;
    font-size:2;
}
</style>
```

Hope you understand what I am trying to do. I just want several different CSS table definitions.

Comment: You need to use a unit when specifying the font size. `1` is meaningless.

Comment: Really you should use classes. That way you can define different styles based on class.

Comment: Use `id` or `class` for tables or you can access them with `nth` pseudo class. e.g. `table:nth-of-type(1)`. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Daw76/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set them to classes or IDs.
CSS:

```
.table1 {
    width: 10%;
    border: 0;
    font-size:6;
}
.table2 { 
    width: 2%;
    border: 1;
    font-size:8;
}
#table3 {
    border: 2;
    font-size:2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table1"></table>

<table class="table2"></table>

<table id="table3"></table>
```